# Is it possible to query a geopackage (.gpkg) for features within a given bounding box?

Tags: r, sf, geopackage, spatial-query

I have GIS data with a very large layer stored within a geopackage from where I want to select features that fall within a bounding box calculated in my R session. I begin by creating a query string:

```
query<-"SELECT * FROM buildings where ST_Intersects(geom, 'SRID=3006; POLYGON((753028 , 7084328, 764500,7093410))');"
```

Then I use it in an `st_read` call:

```
buildings<-st_read(dsn="database.gpkg",layer="buildings", query=query,driver="GPKG")
```

The result is the entire layer, and not the subset that I had intended. Is there anything else I have to do in order to be able to run these spatial queries?

EDIT: I have also tried a different version of the query:

```
query<-"SELECT * FROM buildings where ST_Intersects(geom, ST_GeomFromText( POLYGON((753028 , 7084328, 764500,7093410))',3006)));"
```

Comment: [EPSG::3006](http://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3006) has axes of Northing/Easting, is it possible you have the axes in the wrong order in your bounding box?

Comment: It may be. I am just passing the results of `sf` `st_bbox` to a `paste()` call that builds the query.

Comment: So `st_bbox( )` gives me coordinates in the order: `xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax`. Do you reckon that I'd need them to be `xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax` instead?

Comment: What if you use [ogrinfo](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gdalUtils/versions/2.0.1.14/topics/ogrinfo) with -spat option

Comment: The problem is what are X and Y?  Generally X should be taken as the first listed axis (North) and Y the second listed axis (East)

Comment: `ogrinfo("database.gpkg",layer="layername", spat=st_bbox(polygon_of_interest))` gives me info on the features I want to select. It looks like that `c(xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax) ` works there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101093/discussion-between-kenji-and-nmtoken).

Comment: See how to do native SQL queries with r-tree index from https://erouault.blogspot.com/2017/03/dealing-with-huge-vector-geopackage.html.

Comment: Generally `ST_GeomFromText( POLYGON((753028 , 7084328, 764500,7093410))',3006)` is nothing. Polygon must have at least four points and the first and the last one must be the same.

Comment: Did you ever find a working solution? Having a similar problem. Non spatial queries are working as expected (e.g. variable > 10) and return a subset of the data, but no luck with st_intersects...

Comment: No. I still unable to make spatial queries, so I just switched to a workflow based on non-spatial ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realise that this question is old, but I wanted to leave a reply for future reference. I was also trying to include a spatial filter in the query argument of `st_read()`.
Instead of using the query argument there is a dedicated WKT filter implemented as argument of the function. You can use this to include a bounding box as filter.

```
library(sf)
# Convert bounding box geometry to WKT
bboxWKT <- POLYGON((1 2,1 4,3 4,3 2,1 2))
# Alternative if you want to use an sf as direct input 
bboxWKT <- st_as_text(st_geometry(bbox))
# Apply bbox as spatial filter 
buildings <- st_read(dsn="database.gpkg",
                     layer="buildings", 
                     wkt_filter=bboxWKT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that;

```
SELECT * FROM buildings WHERE (buildings.geom && ST_MakeEnvelope(753028,7084328,764500,7093410, 3006))
```